# frida attach to android native process crash

Tags: android, frida

I am using frida 16.2.1 on android13 device. frida server is running on device successfully but below command crash:

```
$ frida-trace -U -i "encode*" media.swcodec 
Failed to attach: unexpected crash while trying to allocate memory
```

Comment: The quotes in your posted command-line look strange, is this a typo or have you really those double quotes? Have you tried different processes if you can trace them? What is the Android version running on the phone?

Comment: I am rnning frida on Android13 device. That command is copied from internet. and I try -p <pid> as well, results the same. I try system_server, it works fine

Comment: No matter where you got the command from the quotes are wrong, use standard double quotes. Not sure if this has an effect, but I wouldn't use special characters like these in a terminal. The media.swcodec process may implement anti-debugging measures or it is just a bug in frida. Try older versions of frida and frida-server.

Comment: got it, it's a typo, I fixed it. thanks.

Comment: What typo? Please share your new inspiration.

Comment: I fixed the "double quotes" typo. still no progress yet.

Comment: I mean the double quote typo. Just found android below code cause such behavior: SetUpMinijail(kSystemSeccompPolicyPath, kVendorSeccompPolicyPath);. Minijial stuff should be some anti-hack code. Let me remove it to try.

Comment: removing might cause a bootloop, just return at the beginning if the setup